# Where can I find clinical trial data published in JAMA?

Tags: data, clinical-trial

Data in the paper:

http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=336799

is cited in the statistical analysis in the book [Clinical Trial Data Analysis using R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439840202). Can anyone help me find it?

Comment: Are trying to access the paper (question answered by @BenWelborn) or are you trying to get the data (spreadsheet;question I tried to answer to) used for this paper?

Comment: The full article: [Effects of Treatment on Morbidity in Hypertension](https://profiles.nlm.nih.gov/ps/access/XFBBFN.pdf).

Comment: Data, spreadsheet would be nice.

Comment: Can you give a more precise pointer to where (chapter/section/page number) in the book they're discussed?  I couldn't find it in a quick skim through the Google books version ...

Comment: page 33, chapter 3 "treatment comparisons in clinical trials"

Comment: which edition? In the preview on Amazon, p. 33 is in section 1.6.1 - 1.6.2 ??

Comment: Is this data something that is not already given in the article? I think the author of the book must have compiled the data given in the tables in the form of an excel sheet (or other modern formats) and re-analysed them.

Comment: I'm kind of stumped -- I've searched through the available previews of all three editions on Amazon and can't find the section you're referring to ...

Comment: Raw data is not in the article.

Comment: I have edited your question so that the title gives a reader an idea of what "this" is, and the question can be read independently of the title. Please try to emulate this style in any future questions you may ask.

Answer (score 2):

**Online repository**

Today, most journals (although t may depend on the field) require author to upload their data. The paper you are interested in was published in 1967 (internet was invented in 1969). It is very likely that the data have not been uploaded. It is also possible that the data have never been compiled numerically but is only on paper.

**Ask the authors**

Your best chance is to contact the authors directly and politely ask if they can give you their data. The author might be hard to contact as well as they may have changed university, be retired or even dead.

**Possible loss of data**

If you can contact the authors, then it is not unlikely that the data have just been lost. The loss might be due to a flood, to a technical issue or just because they don't know where it was placed.

Comment: alternatively you could try contacting the book authors. Sometimes data used in a book are available from a web page associated with the book, but [this](http://ca.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470887656.html) is the only associated web page I could find, and it doesn't appear to have any associated supplementary materials.  You could also try asking on http://opendata.stackexchange.com/ , although I don't think your chances are very good.